# I broke the sata data port of SATA/PATA/IDE Drive to USB 2.0 Adapter Converter Cable

Tags: motherboard, external-hard-drive, computer-building, adapter, connector

I bought a  SATA/PATA/IDE Drive to USB 2.0 Adapter Converter Cable such as this product:

[Similar product on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HO07GNW)

However, the sata data plastic panel removed (pulled out) and the last copper pin cutted which is GND as I googled (as well as the fixation part was broken).
[This panel was took off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t50Bj.jpg)
I am planning to assembel it pack to the board, without the broken pin and then use it as usually.
Would this work? or it will be dangerous or harmful to the external hard disk.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Without the GND pin the device is unlikely going to work properly

Comment: I would be inclined to replace the cable. The break and then pushing on the connector can change the electrical characteristics of the connection.

Comment: Thanks to both of You. Regarding the GND the first pin is also for GND??, I thought the last pin is -may be- supportive only

Comment: @John, The problem is in the board of the adapter not the cable see the picture. Pushing the connector will keep the arrangement of the sata pins right order, The problem is that the last pin is absence in this case

Comment: Thanks. The picture appeared to be of the cable. But as was suggested in an earlier post, the absence of a grounding pin can cause issues (possible ground loops or like disturbances)

Comment: Thanks much @John, This is the piece that was pulled out see the arrow https://i.stack.imgur.com/t50Bj.jpg ; I will wait to check if anybody tried wiring a similar manner without one of the GNDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You everyone,
last week I got a failing HD and tried this on and it was working (moving and copying some files of winrar and testing).
I use this broken sata adapter on a healthy drive and it worked well, and for a week now I did not encounter any issues even there was a broken pin.
Just pushed the pins in the plastic sata channels.
Note: I done this on my own without any responsibility for damage.